# Arnold's Trivium problem 69

Tags: contour-integration, harmonic-functions, solid-angle

Does anyone have solution for Arnold's Trivium problem #69? Prove that the solid angle based on a given closed contour is a function of the vertex of the angle that is harmonic outside of the contour.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

There might be better / more visual solutions, but: Choose a surface $\Sigma$ bounded by the contour, then your function is
$$f(\vec x) = \int_\Sigma \frac{\vec n(\vec z)\cdot (\vec x-\vec z)}{\Vert \vec x-\vec z\Vert^{-2}} dS(\vec z)$$
where $\vec n(\vec z)$ is the unit normal vector to $\Sigma$ at $\vec z\in\Sigma$
(since $\frac{\vec n(\vec z)\cdot (\vec x-\vec z)}{\Vert \vec x-\vec z\Vert^{-2}} dS(\vec z)$ is the solid angle based on the surface element $dS$). The integrant $\frac{\vec n\cdot (\vec x-\vec z)}{\Vert \vec x-\vec z\Vert^{-2}}$ is a harmonic function of $\vec x$ because it's the dipole potential; alternatively, it is harmonic since $1/\Vert\vec x\Vert$ is harmonic and since $$\partial_{\vec n} \frac1{\Vert\vec x\Vert} = \frac{\vec n\cdot \vec x}{\Vert \vec x\Vert^{-2}}.$$
Hence $f$ is harmonic.